# What are the benefits of XNU using Mach features compared to a full FreeBSD kernel?

Tags: unix, kernel, darwin

The Darwin kernel is a hybrid of Mach and FreeBSD. What are the benefits of using such a hybrid architecture compared to a full FreeBSD kernel?

I'm not looking for subjective opinions of why this architecture was chosen, but am rather interested in technological benefits of the architecture, both from a perspective of today and a perspective of the end of the 1990ies.

- Which improvements do the Mach features offer over their FreeBSD counterparts?
- What features would be difficult to offer without Mach? Are there things possible with Mach with regards to performance or security that a FreeBSD-only kernel would not allow?

Comment: We love good subjective questions, but this needs work to define what a benefit is. Is this about benefits to Apple’s engineering team in developing and supporting? Is it about performance of some specific task? Perhaps if you laid out what results you seek and how experience and/or opinions on 30 years of what Apple has done we can revisit the hold.

Comment: @bmike I added a clarification of the kind of benefits I am looking for and I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: So, the edit is a great start but I see more questions instead of fewer. What problem is being solved here and for whom? When you say features, is that SDK or API or like Finder tags for instance. We may need to work in [chat] or [meta] if my input isn’t enough to get you to some reopen votes.

Comment: @Wilbert I think your focus on "features" won't really find something. You can basically create the same functionality with a micro-kernel as you can with a monolithic kernel - it's "how it is made" that is the difference here. Traditionally you would say that micro-kernels have worse performance than monolithic kernels (as performance is usually one of the main reasons for making a monolithic kernel anyway). I also don't think it is reasonable to compare "Mach features" with "FreeBSD counterparts" - i.e. there are parts of Mach that does not have a counterpart in FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that it is a bit too simplistic to say that the Darwin kernel is simply a hybrid of Mach and FreeBSD.

Trying to look at without the historic implications of why the architecture was chosen doesn't really make sense either. If you were to design a new operating system today, you wouldn't end up with the same result, as the choices available are vastly different now.

You have to remember that Darwin did not just "pop into existence" by merging source codes of Mach and FreeBSD. That is not at all the case. Instead Darwin descend from Rhapsody, which also a heavily customized mix of components such as OSFMK (Mach), 4.4BSD and Yellow Box (which would eventually become Cocoa).

If you have to look at the "objective benefits", you would find that there's probably few to none when looking at the choice between the current "hybrid-kernel" and a hypothetical monolithic Darwin kernel.

If you want to compare it to the actual FreeBSD kernel as of today, there's a huge amount of advantages - mostly related to the fact that Darwin can run Apple's existing code base.

Comment: That is not far enough back. Next Step used mac kernel, freebsd users pace an the gui was the direct predessor of cocoa, that's why the classnanes begin with NS

Comment: We are all aware of that - but this was a question about Darwin, and I'm telling where Darwin came from. As I mentioned it descended from Rhapsody - which incidentally is the successor to NeXTSTEP... basically NeXTSTEP was renamed Rhapsody after Apple purchased NeXT... and later that became Darwin when Mac OS X was released. The influence from 4.4BSD didn't come until Rhapsody, and this is where they "lined up" with FreeBSD at the time.